# .htaccess: Hide URL variables

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have no idea how to play with .htaccess file to change / hide variables from URL

I want to use .htaccess file of **WordPress**
my .htaccess file already contains this scripts:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my_site/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /my_site/index.php 

    [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

I have url

```
http://localhost/my_site/project-detail/?pro_id=7
```

and I want to either hide **pro_id=7** like

```
http://localhost/my_site/project-detail/
```

but could be able to catch this $_GET['pro_id'] in my php script file.

or

```
http://localhost/my_site/project-detail/7
```

I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^project-detail/(.*) /project-detail/?pro_id=$1
```

Comment: What have you tried? What terms have you used in searching for a tutorial about this?

Comment: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^project-detail/([0-9]+)$ project-detail/?pro_id=$1
```

Comment: URL rewriting doesn't change your source code, you have to modify the way you display your URLs

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding these above the `RewriteBase /my_site/` directive, as they need to be before your wordpress stuff.

First, you can access the actual request directly to redirect to the URLs without the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /my_site/project-detail/?\?pro_id=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /my_site/project-detail/%1?%2 [R=301,L]
```

This will make it so a URL like this: `http://localhost/my_site/project-detail/?pro_id=7` gets **redirected** to `http://localhost/my_site/project-detail/7` and a URL like `http://localhost/my_site/project-detail/?pro_id=7&other=param` gets **redirected** to `http://localhost/my_site/project-detail/7?other=param`. If you don't want any extra params at all, remove the **%2** from the rule's target. This makes it so the browser's address bar changes to the URL without the `pro_id` query string. Now we have to internally rewrite it back to the query string:

```
RewriteRule ^my_site/project-detail/([^/]+)$ /my_site/project-detail/?pro_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So internally, the URI gets rewritten back to `/my_site/project-detail/?pro_id=7` but the browser's address bar still has the clean looking URL.